# Accessing value of index of array within array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays called $excelData. print_r($excelData) returns the following:

```sql
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
              [0] => Array ( 
                              [0] => name 
                              [1] => test 
                              [2] => 4 
                              [3] => test@test.com 
                              [4] => it4249 
                              [5] => sha256:1000: 
                             ) 
              ) 
[1] => Array ( 
              [0] => Array ( 
                              [0] => fseconf 
                              [1] => test2 
                              [2] => 3 
                              [3] => example@test.com 
                              [4] => ft9655 
                              [5] => sha256:1000: 
                                         ) 
               ) 
)
```

and I'm trying to print the 4th index in each case (i.e. it4249 and ft955) with the following code:

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO tblTest (username, fname, surname, year, email) VALUES";
$qPart = array_fill(0, count($excelData), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query .=  implode(",",$qPart);
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$i = 1;

print_r($excelData);
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

Foreach($excelData As $Row){

          echo "Username: ".$Row[0][4];
          echo "<br />";
          echo "<br />";
          $sth->bindValue($i++, $Row[0][4]);
          $sth->bindValue($i++, $Row[0][0]);
          $sth->bindValue($i++, $Row[0][1]);
          $sth->bindValue($i++, $Row[0][2]);
          $sth->bindValue($i++, $Row[0][3]); 
 }
```

But it simply prints it4249 both times. Why does this not work and how do I get this right?

**EDIT:**

Changing my loop to pass by reference as below solves my problem but I have no idea why - any explanations?

```php
Foreach($excelData As &$Row){
}
```

Comment: It works fine with me, so there's something else wrong.

Comment: Code works fine for me.

Comment: Oh strange - I've added the rest of my code in that loop in case there's something else going on?

Comment: What does $sth show? Also the same values or diffrent ones? And you can do `$Row[0][4]` without the quotes.

Comment: How would I echo that?

Comment: You could see that in your database, I suppose. Does it insert two rows or just one?

Comment: It doesn't add either - that field is a primary key so due to the fact I'm always getting the same value my Insert statement fails completely

Comment: See if you can add one row at a time. Start with `$Row=$excelData[0]` and then `$Row=$excelData[1]`. If one of them fails there probably is something wrong with the array. And remove the qoutes from `$Row['0']['4']);` It should be `$Row[0][4]);`

Comment: I've removed the quotes in my code. Tried doing row by row like you suggested but I get the exact same result. The print_r statement still prints the array as like above so I'm confused as to what could be wrong with it?

Comment: $Row = $excelData[0] and $Row = $excelData[1] both return what I would expect to be contained by $Row = $excelData[0]

Answer (score 1):

A little snippet to possibly find where it goes wrong. Place if before you define your query to see if it ouputs what you expect, and if it's ok after the query, and so on.

```
<?php
 reset($excelData);
 echo count($excelData)."<br>"; //should be 2
    do{
      echo 'KEY: '.key($excelData); //fist 0, then 1
       $tmp=current($excelData);
       echo '<pre>'.print_r($tmp,true).'</pre><br>';
       }
    while(next($excelData));
?>
```

It gives me the output you showed. If not, there's defenitely something wrong with your array.

Comment: Yep putting this snippet directly before my Foreach loop gives me the exact array output I have above that I expect. Within my Foreach loop I'm still just echoing the same value twice though.

Comment: Maybe, and it's just a maybe, `print_r($excelData)` causes a problem. If you remove that? or make it `print_r($excelData,true)`?

Answer (score 0):

Nest down 3 times.

```
foreach ($other as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $arr1)
    {
        foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v)
        {
        if($k==4)
        {
            echo $v.'<br/>';
            break; // as suggested by u_mulder
        }
        }
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
it4249
ft9655
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/99777)

Comment: Use `break` then to stop executing last `foreach` after proper value found.

Comment: if `($k==4)` works then there's no need to loop further last foreach. `if($k==4) { echo $v.'<br/>'; break; }`

Comment: Oh you are right. Added the `break;` Gave your creds in the code.

Comment: Supporting the theory that the error is not where I thought it was - this also doesn't work for me it also prints the first value twice

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code . It works. There may be some problem with your array()

check demo

[Check demo](https://eval.in/99797)